# Connections qml dial and slider in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a dial and a slider, in mainwindow.cpp I have:

```
ui->quickWidget_3->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///slider.qml"));
ui->quickWidget_4->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///dial.qml"));
```

I want that when I move slider dial moves..

---

I wrote:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QSlider>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

setStyleSheet("background-color:white");

ui->quickWidget->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("yourObject",ui->horizontalSlider);
ui->quickWidget_2->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("yourObject1",ui->horizontalSlider_3);


QObject* item = ui->quickWidget_3->rootObject();
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(moved()), SLOT(sliderMoved()));



ui->quickWidget_2->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///sl.qml"));
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///qml.qml"));

ui->quickWidget_3->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///slider.qml"));

ui->quickWidget_4->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///dial.qml"));






ui->horizontalSlider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:vertical {background-color:red; position:absolute; left:4px; right: 4px}");
//connect circularGauge e text
```

}

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
      delete ui;
  }


void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_2_sliderMoved(int position)
{
    ui->dial->setValue(position);




}

void MainWindow::sliderMoved()
{
    QObject* slider = ui->quickWidget_3->rootObject();
    QObject* dial = ui->quickWidget_4->rootObject();
     qreal value = QQmlProperty::read(slider, "value").toReal();
    QQmlProperty::write(dial, "value", value);
 }
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: dial and slider are built with qml

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: dial in qml: Dial {
        id: control
        width: 92
        height: 100

        stepSize: 1
        from:0
        to:100

Comment: slider in qml:Slider {
    id: control
    to: 100
    value: 0.5

    background: Rectangle {
        x: control.leftPadding
        y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 4
        width: control.availableWidth
        height: implicitHeight
        radius: 2
        color: "#000000"

        Rectangle {
            width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
            height: parent.height
            color: "#ffd1dc"
            radius: 2
        }
    }

Comment: Never put code in the comments since they look horrible, if you want help edit your question and add it there, read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour] if you have not done so

Comment: very very bad idea to place several qml inside several `QQuickWidget`s. You should either base you application on `QML` or `QWidget` without mixing them.

Comment: but I use in mainwindow elements of mainwindow and elements of qml, so I have to mix them

Answer (score 0):

It is well documented here: [Interacting with QML Objects from C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html)

Please try to provide full relevant working code in your questions next time, like I'm going to do in this answer. Doing so, you will increase the chance of an answer.

test.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets quickwidgets quickcontrols2
[...]
```

dial.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Dial {
    id: control
    from: 0
    to: 100
    stepSize: 1
    value: 0
}
```

slider.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Slider {
    id: control
    from: 0
    to: 100
    stepSize: 1
    value: 0
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void sliderMoved();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QQmlProperty>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->quickWidget_1->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/slider.qml"));
    ui->quickWidget_2->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/dial.qml"));

    QObject* item = ui->quickWidget_1->rootObject();
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(moved()), SLOT(sliderMoved()));
}

void MainWindow::sliderMoved()
{
    QObject* slider = ui->quickWidget_1->rootObject();
    QObject* dial = ui->quickWidget_2->rootObject();
    qreal value = QQmlProperty::read(slider, "value").toReal();
    QQmlProperty::write(dial, "value", value);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Maybe. But are you able to write the error text so everybody can take a look?